# Saving selected features by default in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, layers, select, save

Is it possible in QGIS (2.14 or higher) to check by default "Save only selected features" when saving a layer and when features are selected ?

Comment: That would be a great UX enhancement and not hard to do at all. If you have some coding experience, that should be trivial, if not, you can send a developer a private message and try to convince him ;)

Comment: You could also use the `Save selected features` tool from the **Processing Toolbox** which would _save_ you from having to enable the option constantly.

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn - I'm guessing you just need to change [this line](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/7d8fba8b8c1a2e39b0814053029bf64c20e85c73/src/app/ogr/qgsvectorlayersaveasdialog.cpp#L65) to `setEnabled`? :)

Comment: @Joseph looking forward to your [pull request](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pulls) :)

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn - [Done](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/3614)...I think (first time using GitHub!).